# creating sentance from word list x amount of times

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So I have been learning python and I am working on a little project. I have run into a problem though.

What I am trying to do is get the program to pick x amount of words from a text file and then repeating that task x amount of times.

So lets say for example I wanted to have 5 words in the sentence and do this 3 times. The result would be the following:

```
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
word1 word2 word3 word4 word5
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

word_file = "words.txt" #find word file
Words = open(word_file).read().splitlines() #retrieving and sorting word file

sent = random.randrange(0,1100) #amount of words to choose from in list
print(Words[sent]) #print the words
```

That will generate one word from the list of 1100 words. So then I tried to repeat this task x amount of times but instead it just repeated the same randomly chosen word x amount of times.

Here is that code:

```
import random

word_file = "words.txt" #find word file
Words = open(word_file).read().splitlines() #retreiving and sorting word file
sent = random.randrange(0,1100) #amount of words to choose from in list

for x in range(0, 3): #reapeat 3 times
   print(Words[sent]) #print the words
```

So I am running in to two problems really. The first is that it is repeating the same word that was chosen first and second it will do it in each individual line instead of x amount then next line.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction to sorting this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to recompute a new random number each time.

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    sent = random.randrange(0,1100)
    print(Words[sent])
```

Though what might be easier for your case is to use the built in `random.choices()` function:

```
print(random.choices(Words, k=3))
```

Will print a list of 3 random words from your `Words` list.

If you aren't using Python 3.6, then you can just call `random.choice(Words)` over and over again.

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response and your answer it worked perfectly. Still trying to get my head around python abit. Think I might read another book again to learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain your code a little bit:

```
sent = random.randrange(0,1100) # <= returns a random number in range 0 => 1100 , this will not be changed.
for x in range(0, 3):
    print(Words[sent]) # <= This line will print the word at the position sent, 3 times with the same Words and sent so it will be repeated the same word 3 times.
```

To fix this, you need to random a number each time you want a new word to be outputted.

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    sent = random.randrange(0,1100)
    print(Words[sent])
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining the code further to me. All makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

you could abstract it to a function

```
def my_function(x,y):
    #your code here

#you script goes here
my_function(x,y)
```

you are only generating the random number once, you could need to generate another random number for it to be different (thats where the function could help a lot). Make sure your function definition is before you call it.